# Difference in coefs using garch() and ugarchfit()

Tags: r, time-series, difference, coefficients

I try to fit a GARCH(1,1) to the log-returns of the german stock index (dax) data from 2014-06-03 till 2016-01-01 using `ugarchfit` from the `ugarch`. I found that there is a difference to the coefs calculated by using `garch` from `tseries`.

Why there is a difference and which one is the more precise?

Here is my code:

```
library("tseries")
library("rugarch")

# GARCH(1,1)-Specification using rugarch-package
specgarch0 <- ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)), mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0)), distribution="norm")
dax_mod0<- ugarchfit(data=dax_ret, spec=specgarch0)
show(dax_mod0)
coef(dax_mod0)

# GARCH(1,1)-Specification using garch(...) by tseries-Package
dmod<-garch(dax_ret)
summary(dmod)
dmod$coef


> dmod$coef
          a0           a1           b1 
9.763928e-06 1.001589e-01 8.496407e-01 

> coef(dax_mod0)
          mu        omega       alpha1        beta1 
6.105980e-04 1.022263e-05 1.036797e-01 8.436064e-01
```

Comment: For this to be reproducible you'd need to provide `dax_ret`

Comment: how do I do it? is it possible to attache a csv-file?